# how to update data from query to table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a data from this query:

```
with countedresult As  
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d_hotbox order by d.D_hotbox,d.start_date) as ADS,d.ID,
           d.D_hotbox,
           d.D_PWM_location,
           d.start_date,
           d.Last_date--, 
           h.SERIAL_NUMBER
    from   D_FLEET d
) 
select   countedresult.ID,
         countedresult.D_HOTBOX,        
         countedresult.D_PWM_location,
         countedresult.start_date,
         countedresult.Last_date, 
         LAG(ID, 1) over (partition by d_hotbox order by d_hotbox, start_date) as previous_id, 
         ads HB_Run_Number
from     countedresult
order by d_hotbox, HB_Run_Number DESC
```

I have to update only two columns in the table they are PREVIOUS_ID, RUN_NO.

I want to insert these value in another table

```
[dbo].[D_FLEET]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[D__LOCATION] [int] NOT NULL,
[D_BOX] [int] NULL,
[D__MODULE] [int] NULL,
[ST_DATE] [date] NULL,
[LT_DATE] [date] NULL,
[S_START_DATE] [date] NULL,
[S_LAST_DATE] [date] NULL,
[LT_DATE_@1A] [date] NULL,
[C_LAST_SS] [float] NULL,
[S_AVG] [float] NULL,
[SP_MIN] [float] NULL,
[SP_MAX] [float] NULL,
[H_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[R_FRU] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[NILD] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RLACE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[HRADE] [float] NULL,
[HTUS] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[HDULE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[HT_DATE] [date] NULL,
[OAG] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ID_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
[UPDATED_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
[Run_Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RUN_NO] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PREVIOUS_ID] [int] NULL
)
```

I want to update the values from :

1. *Previous_id* from the query to *PREVIOUS_ID* from the table D_FLEET with reference to the ID column.
2. *HB_RUN_NUMBER* from query to *[RUN_NO]* from table D_FLEET with reference to the ID column.

What is this the correct way to do it?

I am unable to understand how to do it as I am doing the update from query to table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with countedresult As  
( select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by d_hotbox order by start_date) as ADS
       , LAG(ID, 1)   over (partition by d_hotbox order by start_date) as previous_id
       , ID
    from D_FLEET 
) 
update D_FLEET 
   set HB_RUN_NUMBER = countedresult.ADS 
     , PREVIOUS_ID   = countedresult.PREVIOUS_ID 
  from D_FLEET  
  join countedresult 
    on D_FLEET.ID = countedresult.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join your result to the target table and update as it shown below.

Pay attention to `JOIN` (there is a mistake in criteria) and how we use an alias in `UPDATE`.

```
with countedresult As  
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d_hotbox order by d.D_hotbox,d.start_date) as ADS,d.ID,
           d.D_hotbox,
           d.D_PWM_location,
           d.start_date,
           d.Last_date--, 
           h.SERIAL_NUMBER
    from   D_FLEET d
)
UPDATE T
SET
     RUN_NO = LAG(ID, 1) over (partition by d_hotbox order by d_hotbox, start_date)
     PREVIOUS_ID = ads
from     countedresult
join     D_FLEET AS T ON T.ID = countedresult.ID
order by d_hotbox, HB_Run_Number DESC
```

Comment: this is the error is am getting for this line"RUN_NO = LAG(ID, 1) over (partition by d_hotbox order by d_hotbox, start_date)" Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.